# ZyWall USG 50 locked out

Tags: firewall, zyxel, zywall

A Friend of mine was testing something in our Server Room. He made a firewall Rule on the Zywalls' web-interface like this:

Block All from All to Zywall

So, now we cant access the Webpannel anymore (logic..) ATM we can only access the Servers behind it (We aren't physically there) and we need to change a Port-forwarding.. is there any other way to access the ZyWall and delete this Rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to connect a console cable to the Zywall's DB-9 port in order to gain access via CLI.  I would disable the firewall with `no firewall activate`

Then quickly log in via browser to add a rule allowing yourself (LAN) access to the device (Zywall) before reenabling the firewall itself.

Been there, done that.